# Change Kendo MVC Grid pagination dropdown value programatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've got a Telerik MVC Server Side Grid with pagination, the component generates a pagination dropdown at the bottom of the table which lets you select the page size.

I would like to change the value of that dropdown programatically from javascript and make it so the grid triggers a refresh with the new value.

I have already tried targetting the dropdown itself like so:

```
var listViewPagerDropDownList = $(".k-pager-sizes").find("select").data("kendoDropDownList");
listViewPagerDropDownList.value(userPreferencePageSize);
```

Targetting the pager:

```
var pager = $(".k-grid-pager").data("kendoPager");
pager.pageSize(userPreferencePageSize);
```

As well as trying to change it manually with jQuery like so:

```
var selectBox = $(".k-pager-sizes").find("select");
selectBox.val(userPreferencePageSize);
selectBox.find("option[value='" + userPreferencePageSize + "']").prop("selected", true);
```

But no matter what I do, it has no effect. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Confused as to what you actually want, but to change the pagesizes you need to access the pager's dropdownlist datasource that holds the page values:

```
// Add a page size of 25 to the dropdown
$("select[data-role='dropdownlist']").data('kendoDropDownList').dataSource.add({text: "25", value: "25"});
```

You could use other [datasource commands](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource) to clear existing values.

If you just want to change the page size of the grid, try:

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.pageSize(numberOfRows);
```

Comment: Your answer is naturally correct but for Kendo UI not for Kendo MVC, they may work together well since they were built on the same base but are essentially 2 different frameworks. In case of Kendo MVC Grid changing the page size of the data source results with Kendo UI controls results in malfunctioning filters of the grid. I raised a question about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54256083/presetting-kendo-datasource-pagesize-to-all . Since that did not work, I am not trying to just make Kendo MVC fire the event itself... but the grid is making it very difficult to modify its DOM

Comment: No, they are not - see [here](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/kendo-ui-vs-mvc-wrappers). The MVC product simply "wraps" up all the javascript stuff for you. There are some things (like this) you simply cannot do with the wrappers. Confusing because you are essentially doing the same thing in your question example on different widgets.

Comment: Kendo UI generates the DOM with Javascript while Kendo MVC does that on the server-side with C#. In most cases the resulting DOM structure is completely different and the controls do not flawlessly work with each other (like in this example). That's why I say they have the same base but are "essentially" 2 different frameworks. Nothing is really confusing here, I am just trying to change the value of a simple dropdown but Telerik as usually makes it very difficult :p

Comment: Both methods render essentially the same code depending on the wrapper markup. So if you want to dynamically add to the page size drop down, you need to use a selector for the dropdown that is created by the pager of the grid and then access it's datasource. Have you tried it?